# how do i extract every #nth frame from a video with a python script?

Tags: python, video

how do i extract every #nth frame from a video with a python script?

the one where I don't extract every int(args.framegap) doesn't hang so could anyone show me what i'm doing wrong?

this is my script but it hangs on extracting frames, anyone who knows why or how to fix this?

i also want them named properly, for example if i extract every 5 frames they should be named 001.png , 006.png , 011.png etc..

thanks

```
import argparse
import cv2
import time
import os
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='arguments')

parser.add_argument('--videofile', type=str, help='path to your video file, for example --videofile C:\file\video\extract\video.mp4')
parser.add_argument('--projectname', type=str, help='name of the project to create the directories')
parser.add_argument('--framegap', type=int, help='name of the project to create the directories')

args = parser.parse_args()
doc_path = os.path.expanduser('~\Documents')
data_path = os.path.expanduser('~\Documents\\visionsofchaos\\fewshot\\data')


train_filtered = data_path+str(args.projectname)+'_train'+'\\'+'input_filtered'

#take every #nth frame
def video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc):
    """Function to extract frames from input video file
    and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
    Args:
        input_loc: Input video file.
        output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
    Returns:
        None
    """
    try:
        os.mkdir(output_loc)
    except OSError:
        pass
    # Log the time
    time_start = time.time()
    # Start capturing the feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)
    # Find the number of frames
    video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
    print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)
    count = 0
    print ("Converting video..\n")
    # Start converting the video
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Extract the frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            continue
        # Write the results back to output location.
        if count % int(args.framegap) == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(train_filtered + "/%#03d.png" % (count+1), frame)
            count += 1
        # If there are no more frames left
            if (count > (video_length-1)):
                # Log the time again
                time_end = time.time()
                # Release the feed
                cap.release()
                # Print stats
                print ("Done extracting frames.\n%d frames extracted" % count)
                print ("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
                break

if __name__=="__main__":
    input_loc = args.videofile
    output_loc = data_path + '\\' + args.projectname + '_gen\\input_filtered'
    video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc)
```

Comment: you have to runs `count += 1` outside `if count % int(args.framegap) == 0:` (ie. run it before `if`) - and this can block code because it can't execute `count += 1`

Comment: if you defined `type=int` then you don't have to use `int(...)`

Answer (score 0):

All problem makes wrong indentations

---

You have to run `count += 1` outside `if count % int(args.framegap) == 0:`

You run it inside `if` so after first frame it changes to `count = 1` and later `if` doesn't allow to run anoter `count += 1` so it is always `count = 1` and this blocks all code.

```
count = -1

# loop

        count += 1

        # --- the same indentations ---

        if count % int(args.framegap) == 0:
               #.... code ...
```

or

```
count = 0

# loop


        if count % int(args.framegap) == 0:
               #.... code ...

        # --- the same indentations ---

        count += 1
```

---

I think you should also change indentations with another `if (count > (video_length-1))` because it is also inside `if count % int(args.framegap) == 0:` and it can make problems

```
count = 0

# loop

        if count % int(args.framegap) == 0:
            #.... code ...

        # --- the same indentations ---

        count += 1

        # --- the same indentations ---
     
        if count > (video_length-1):  
            #.... code ...
```

Comment: i tried but it doesn't export anything, it doesn't hang anymore tho..

Comment: you should use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Maybe it needs some other changes. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.